# rails join of a join (rails 2.3.5 and ruby 1.8.7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have

data_records, brands and influencers

data_records have many brands 
data_records have 1 influencer

brands have many influencers via brand_influencers association which has an attribute called top (boolean).

here are my models:

```
class DataRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :influencer
  has_and_belongs_to_many :brands
end

class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :data_records
end

class Influencer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brands_influencers
  has_many :brands, :through => :brands_influencers
end

class BrandsInfluencer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :influencer
end
```

I would like to do one query to get all data_records for a given brand where the influencers are in the brands top influencers (top = true).

I need to start on the data_record model because there are other dynamic queries that can be bolted on to this query (this is a typical big filter type screen).

So my question, is it possible to join in a realtionship of a join. I have used joins brands and it works fine, but I cant figure out a way to join in the brand_influencers relationship

thanks
Joel

Comment: It would be easier to understand this if it were Ruby classes that have the belongs_to, has_many, has_one, etc. AR relationships defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rails 2.3.5 version of it is,

```
DataRecord.find :all, :conditions => ['brands.name = ? AND influencers.top = ?', 'name', true], :joins => {:brands => :influencers}
```

I am supposing there's a name for a brand and you're looking for the brand by name. And you need to change `Brand` like this:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :data_records
    has_and_belongs_to_many :influencers
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use

```
has_many :foos, :through=>:bar
```

or

```
has_one :foo, :through=>:bar
```

---

Try this:

```
class DataRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  # how does this relate to the other models?
end

class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :influencers
end

class Influencer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :brands
end

class BrandsInfluencers < ActiveRecord::Base
  # notice the name change in this class (pluralization)
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :influencer
end
```

Comment: Hi, Im trying to figure out how to write the active record query.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `join` from another and reference them in a `where` like this:

```
DataRecord.joins(:influencers => {:brand_influencers}, :brands).
  where(:brands => {:id => 123}). 
  where(:brands => {:brand_influencers => {:top => true}})
```

I'm pretty sure it works similarly in 2.3.x. Try this:

```
DataRecord.joins(:influencers => {:brand_influencers}, :brands).
  conditions(:brands => {:id => 123}). 
  conditions(:brands => {:brand_influencers => {:top => true}})
```

I would suggest you build up the relation bit by bit and check the SQL that's being generated. Good luck!

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need, but I need the rails 2.3.5 version of it.